# Using Cygwin, how do I aggregate content in 1 column, and then do counts of occurrences in an array from another column?

Tags: arrays, cygwin, multiple-columns

For example:
20150401 A,C,R,AB,CD,EF,EE,FF
20150401 A,C,EF,FF,G
20150401 A,BB,C,EF,FG
20150401 R,AB,CD,EF,G
20150401 R,C,EF,EE,GG
20150402 A,C,EF,FF,G
20150402 D,DD,CD,FF,GG,AB,EE,EE
20150403 R,R,CD,EF,G,EE
20150403 A,C,EF,FF,G
20150403 D,CD,FF,EE,G,GG
20150403 F,EF,G,EE,C,AB

How do I count how many times each item occurs on each date without specifying each item? So ideally the output would give me a list of how many times "A" occurred on 20150401, 20150402, and 20150403. Then it would be give the number of occurrences of "C"  on 20150401, 20150402, and 20150403. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

Save the following as `count.pl`:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %table;
while (<>) {                       # Read the input line by line.
    my ($date, $list) = split;     # Split on whitespace.
    my @items = split /,/, $list;  # Split the list on commas.
    $table{$_}{$date}++ for @items;# Record the occurrences.
}

for my $item (sort keys %table) {                  # Iterate over the items.
    for my $date (sort keys %{ $table{$item} }) {  # Iterate over the dates.
        print "$item $date $table{$item}{$date}\n";
    }
}
```

Then run

```
perl count.pl input-file
```